# Python pymysql dynamic binding the variable value to database field

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to dynamically bind the variable value to be inserted into database table column.

Example variable value in json:

```
document= {'zipCode': '99999', 
           'name': 'tester', 
           'company': 'xxxx'}
```

And my database table column as:

table name: table1

column: id,zip_code,name,company

My code in python:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
     sql = "INSERT INTO table1(zip_code, name, company) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql,(document['zipCode'],
                                document['name'],
                                document['company']))
connection.commit()
```

However, if one of the key-value in document  is absent, definitely the INSERT query will encounter error. i.e. ONLY document['name'] exist in document variable

Any thought to handle this for efficient code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that, generally, ORMs like `SQLAlchemy` or `Peewee` solve pretty easily for you.

But, if I were to implement, I would probably do something "dynamic" based on the available keys:

```
QUERY = "INSERT INTO table1({columns}) VALUES ({values})"


def get_query(document):
   columns = list(document.keys())

   return QUERY.format(columns=", ".join(columns),
                       values=", ".join('%({})s'.format(column) for column in columns))
```

Sample usage:

```
In [12]: get_query({'zipCode': '99999', 'name': 'tester', 'company': 'xxxx'})
Out[12]: 'INSERT INTO table1(company, zipCode, name) VALUES (%(company)s, %(zipCode)s, %(name)s)'

In [13]: get_query({'name': 'tester'})
Out[13]: 'INSERT INTO table1(name) VALUES (%(name)s)'
```

Then, you would just parameterize the query with the `document` dictionary as we've created *named placeholders* in the query:

```
cursor.execute(get_query(document), document)
```

Comment: thanks, Hi @alecxe, how can I rename the document key (zipCode) into table column (zip_code) as your method? Let's say if there are different document key to map into different table column name.

Comment: @JohnnyCc ah, yeah, this solution in this state requires the key names in `document` to match the table columns. You may add an extra dictionary to map things out and it may be okay if the problem is relatively small. You could also switch to using positional placeholders, but you would still need to know the column name per position.